# How to add stored procedure in legacy mode using entity framework 6.1 in the c#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I tried to add **stored procedure** in **Legacy Mode** using **Entity Framework 6.1** in the **c#** because i want to add stored procedure separately to reduce loading and execution time.
I can't able to add it.
And suggest me "How can i add it".

Comment: What's Legacy Mode? Searching give me nothing relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To add Stored Procedure in Legacy Mode:** Please follow below steps to add stored procedure in Legacy Mode...

**Step 1:** Right click on DataLayer folder and **Add** >> **New Item...**

[image]

**Step 2:**

[image]

**Step 3:** Select "**EF Designer from database**" and click on **Next** button

[image]

**Step 4:** Set new database connection and enter connection settings name

[image]

**Step 5:** Select your created **SP** and enter **Model Namespace** name
[image]

**Step 6:** TO delete **.tt** extension files

[image]

**Step 7:** Open **.edmx** file and right click on **.edmx** file & select **properties**
[image]

**Step 8:** Click on **T4** and press **delete** button for **Legacy Mode**
[image]

**Step 9:**

[image]

**Step 10:** Right click on **.edmx** file and open with **XML editor** and change 2012 to 2008

[image]

**Step 11:**

[image]

**Step 12:** Open
[image]

**Step 13:** Open **designer.cs** file and add **ext** prefix on **Function Imports**
[image]

**Step 14:**
[image]

**Step 15:**
[image]